# Allow special character only after alpha-numeric character?

Tags: .net, duplicates

How do I allow a special character but only after alpha-numeric character in VB.net 
I am using vb 2011

i want to be able to insert a pipe (|) but only after alpha-numeric charters and not leading or trailing. In other words I do not want to allow pipes right after one another..

i.e. car|truck|1999|2000 (correct)

verses

|car||truck|1999|||2000| (wrong)

no leading or ending pipes and no multiple pipes side by side. This is a hard one, can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than ignoring keypresses that invalid at certain times, you should look at using regex validation on the final string.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901996/regex-to-validate-the-number-of-pipe-delimited-items) a regex allowing for 3 pipe delimited values, but you can easily extend it:

```
^(?:[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+){0,2})?$
```

Comment: Thank you...half way there. It removes dupplicate pipes but does not remove leading and trailing pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Would also do it with regular expressions:

Use this: `(\|)(?:\|)+` and replace with \1